# Is there a simple way that I can detect when AngularJS has an Ajax call in progress?

Tags: angularjs

Is there a way I can detect when there's an $http or $resource call in progress so that I can show something to the user to indicate that my code is waiting for a reply. Ideally I would like something that could be put in the one place. Not something that I would need to put into the code at the start and finish of every call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interceptor very easily

Here is a sample

```
var mydevices = angular.module('deviceDetails', ['ui.bootstrap', 'tags-input'])

mydevices.config(function ($httpProvider) {
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($q) {
      return {
       'request': function(config) {
           if (config.method === 'GET' && config.url.contains("/rest/")) {
               var sep = config.url.indexOf('?') === -1 ? '?' : '&';
               config.url = config.url + sep + 'cacheSlayer=' + new Date().getTime();
           }
           console.log(config.url);
           return config || $q.when(config);
        }
      };
    });
});
```

The example above intercepts all /rest/ URLs, you can modify based on your requirements

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use this angular module. You just need to register it and it handles all the rest.

http://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/